# Is it a good practice to open a new connection for each front end request when using MySQL and NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

Specifically I'm using MariaDB with Express and its not clear if i need to open a new connection for each request or keep one open like in MongoDB.

So should connection.end(); be used at all?

Comment: It is a bad practice to open a new connection for each query in your Node.js application.  Read about connection pooling for more information.

Comment: It is almost impossible to open 1 connection for each request.
Normally the library reuse the opens connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a bad practice to open a new connection for each request in your Node.js application. You can open a connection, keep it and use in your application. If you have more load on your application, in that case, you can use a connection pool. For more info refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to use a Singelton Design pattern

Create a file db_settings.json

```
{
    host : 'sm',
    user : 'db_username',
    password : 'db_password',
    database : 'database_name'
}
```

Create a file db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var settings = require('./db_settings.json');
var db;

function connectDatabase() {
    if (!db) {
        db = mysql.createConnection(settings);

        db.connect(function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Database is connected!');
            } else {
                console.log('Error connecting database!');
            }
        });
    }
    return db;
}

module.exports = connectDatabase();`
```

And when you need your to connect to Database or to make a query, just import the DB file

```
var db = require('./db');
```